# Stuck creating apk file from sencha touch 2 app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, sencha-touch-2, apk

I´m really stuck on how to create the apk file on my computer of a sencha touch 2 app.

I have follow this [tutorial](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?270566-Building-Sencha-Touch-2-Phonegap-Application-for-Android-Windows) step by step.

But when I arrive at the last point it gives me some erros and I´m unable to solve it.

[image]
[image]

This is the log of the point 6 of the [tutorial](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?270566-Building-Sencha-Touch-2-Phonegap-Application-for-Android-Windows) log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solve my problem. I found that through [this](https://build.phonegap.com/apps) link it autogenerates the files.
Before I discovered that you need to create via sencha cmd the production files through the command in the app folder:
sencha app build production

With this two steps I created the .apk file,donwloaded and tested it.

Answer (score -1):

What JDK version you are using? Check if you have added cordova jar file.

Thanks,
Madan

Comment: For this kind of query, we use "comment"! This is answer place.